# Make search bar responsive when screen size is narrowed?

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive

Im working on a search bar for a website, on a laptop screen/computer screen the search bar width seems fine. Next I want to also make the search bar mobile, tablet responsive as well, im trying to do something below using @media tag, but doesn't seem to be working. when I apply below and I open my website url on a mobile the whole page shrinks adding white spaces, please advice, how to apply the media property?

Below is my code.

```
.form-search{
  width: 50%;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}

@media (max-width:480px) {
  .form-search {
    width: 60%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you add `.form-search` to the input box like below..

```
<input type="text" class="form-search" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a height for the form element. Try modifying your code to something like this:

```
.form-search {
    height: 150px;
}

@media (max-width:480px) {
    .form-search {
       height: 70px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use calc css, and substract other elements width and margins from it.

```
//if for example search button takes fixed 80px on screen:
.form-search {
width: calc(100% - 80px);
}
```